# Riemann Integrals vs Area Under Curve intuition

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, continuity

I have the (infinitely) discontinuous function defined by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n} & x\in(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}$$
Who's graph is as such: [image: Graph]
Now, by inspection the "area under the curve" as is the informal definition of an integral is clearly greater than $\frac{1}{2}$, however using Riemann Integrals to find the integral to 1.d.p. (between $0$ and $1$) I did the following:

### Proof

Let $(\mathscr{D}_{n})=\{0,\frac{1}{n},\ldots,\frac{n-1}{n},1\}$ be the regular dissection of $[0,1]$ of size $n$, then $$l_{\mathscr{D}} =\sum_{j=1}^{n}\inf\{f(x):a_{j-1}\leq x\leq a_{j}\}(a_{j}-a_{j-1})$$
$$u_{\mathscr{D}} =\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sup\{f(x):a_{j-1}\leq x\leq a_{j}\}(a_{j}-a_{j-1})$$
Clearly, $f(x)$ is increasing, so:
$$m_{j}=\inf\left\{ f(x):\frac{j-1}{n}\leq x\leq\frac{j}{n}\right\} \\=f\left(\frac{j-1}{n}\right)\\=\frac{j-1}{n}$$
$$M_{j}=\sup\left\{ f(x):\frac{j-1}{n}\leq x\leq\frac{j}{n}\right\} \\=f\left(\frac{j}{n}\right)\\=\frac{j}{n}$$
So our Riemann sums are: $$l_{\mathscr{D}_{n}}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{(j-1)}{n}\\=\frac{1}{n^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(k)\\=\frac{1}{n^{2}}\left(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right)\\=\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{n})$$
and
$$u_{\mathscr{D}_{n}}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{j}{n}\\=\frac{1}{n^{2}}\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)\\=\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{n})$$
Then, obviously $\lim u_{\mathscr{D}_{n}} = \lim l_{\mathscr{D}_{n}}=\frac{1}{2}$ so $\intop_{0}^{1} f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$. So my question is this, why is my answer counter to the "Intuitive" idea of area under a curve, is it just this is a poor way of estimating the integral? Do the infinite points of discontinuity make a difference to the idea of "area under a curve"? Is my method even correct? Thank you.

Comment: You managed to have some errors in your calculation...

Comment: @user12986714 May you point out which line in particular things appear to go wrong?

Comment: $l_{\mathscr{D}_{n}}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{(j-1)}{n}$ (read that again, and the definition of Riemann sum again)

Comment: @user12986714 We have been given the definition Lower sum = $\sum_{j=1}^{n} m_j (a_{j} - a_{j-1})$, now unless my $m_j$ is incorrect I don't see the issue?

Comment: think again about how you moved $a_j-a_{j-1}$ part out of the sum sign...

Comment: @user12986714 Because it is a regular dissection of size n $(a_{j} - a_{j-1})=\frac{1}{n}$ where n is some positive integer, it's a constant and therefore can be taken out of the sum though?

Comment: Do you really think that the length of the lines showed in the graph is some constant? (think about the difference between $1-\frac 1 2$ and $\frac 1 2 -\frac 1 3$)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107592/discussion-between-jacob-and-user12986714).

Comment: Firstly, the definition of $f$ has an error. It seems like you meant $(\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}]$ instead of $(\frac{1}{n-1}, \frac{1}{n}],$ which would be bad notation sicne $\frac{1}{n-1} > \frac{1}{n}$. Next, in your computations, $f(j/n) = j/n$ is wrong. For instance, from the picture you put up, $f(2/3) = 1$.